# android - Buttons not working in calculator app

Tags: android, android-studio, button, textview

I have built a calculator app which uses EditTexts for you to insert the two values, and then I also have 4 Buttons each with an operation (eg.+,-,/,x). It seems though as if the buttons aren't doing its function assigned to it, No value is being sent to the TextView. Could you please help me in making those buttons do its operation?

Here is my code below:

```
package com.example.user.zidcalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int enter1;
    int enter2;
    int newHeight;
    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    TextView tv;
    Button bt1;
    Button bt2;
    Button bt3;
    Button bt4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvans);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        bt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        newHeight = et2.getHeight();
        tv.setHeight(newHeight);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                enter1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                enter2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

                int answer = enter1 + enter2;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(answer));

            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                enter1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                enter2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

                int answer = enter1 - enter2;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(answer));

            }
        });

        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                enter1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                enter2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

                int answer = enter1 * enter2;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(answer));

            }
        });

        bt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                enter1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                enter2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

                int answer = enter1 / enter2;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(answer));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter two numbers below and perform an operation to see the output"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter first  number here -->"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter second  number here -->"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Answer -->"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvans"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:text="x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:text="/"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your layout file here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra I've uploaded the Layout/XML file.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

When you getHeight of et2, it haven't text, so it height is 0. Then, you set height 0 for tv, you can't see it in screen althought it has text.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to run the code giving a constant height and width to answerTextView,tvans in your code(for eg: 30 DP height and 30 DP width).
This issue is not related to button. This is due to the invisibility of textView due to 0 height and width

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvans"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed the Height variable `newHeight` and everything associated with it.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a solution to your problem or an edit to the original post? If the latter, please remove it as an "answer" and use the edit button in your post for updates.